# requiring optional javascript files with requirejs (e.g. require a locale specific file)

Tags: requirejs

A few of the jquery plugins we rely on offer the ability to include locale/culture specific files to make non-en-us users feel more at home with their functionality (for example, jquery-globalize and bootstrap-datapicker).

The old school way of achieving this was as follows (where 'en-AU' is determined on the fly, sometimes resulting in a 404 for missing cultures):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/globalize/globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.en-AU.js"></script>
```

Is there a recommended way of achieving this with requirejs (note that globalize is included as a shim)?

Here's my first attempt, not yet sure how the requirejs optomizer will handle it...

```
Globalize = require("globalize");
...
locale = module.config().locale;
if (locale != null) {
  require(["globalize/globalize.culture." + locale], function() {
    logger.debug("Loaded locale '" + locale + "'");
    Globalize.culture(locale);
  }, function() {
    logger.debug("Unable to load locale '" + locale + "'");
  });
}
```

edit: the optimizer handles it fine but but the solution doesn't really work because the culture file is loaded asynchronously it's possible that the app has used Globalize before the culture is set.

Comment: have you seen that you can use i18n for localization? http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#i18n found that yesterday.

Comment: @shapeshifta yep, we're using it extensively but as far as I can tell it doesn't work with the scenario described (requires an nls directory etc)

Answer (score 0):

Kendo does something similar in their code.

This is a slight modification of their technique.  This particular style allows the modules to load either through require or direct script inclusion.

I modified it slightly to set up the prereqs.  On the downside, this code will *no longer* work through the r.js optimizer.

```
var myLocalPrereqs = ['file_english.min'];

("function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define : function (preReqs, func) {
    return func()
})(myLocalPrereqs, function () {
    (function () {
      // Your module code goes here...
    })()
});
```